# Lua environments when calling function within setfenv function

Tags: lua, lua-5.1

So I have a Lua script in which I set the environment of a function and define other functions that I make available in the environment.  The issue is that when I call the function I did `setfenv` on, any function it calls within the environment uses the global `_G` environment to lookup values as opposed to the environment I set when calling the initial function.  I have replicated the issue below:

```
> function f() print(t) end
> t = 5
> f()
5
> env = {}
> env['print'] = print
> env['t'] = 7
> env['f'] = f
> setfenv(f, env)
> f()
7
> setfenv(f, _G)
> f()
5
> function g() f() end
> g()
5
> setfenv(g, env)
> g()
5
```

Is there a way to get the environment to propagate to all calls without having to do `setfenv` on every function I want to add to `env` (basically, so that the last call in the example to `g()` would return `7` instead of `5`)?

Using Lua 5.1.

Comment: Function environments in Lua 5.1 are not inherited by function invocation (you have to manually call `setfenv` before calling that function to solve your problem).  New environment system (since 5.2, using _ENV) makes correct inheritance easily possible.

Comment: Is there no way to replicate this behaviour in 5.1?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function so that it automatically changes its own environment on every call

```
-- This code works on Lua 5.1, 5.2, 5.3
local getfenv = getfenv or function() end
local setfenv = setfenv or getfenv

a = 1

function f(env)
   local _ENV = env or getfenv(2) or _ENV; setfenv(1, _ENV)
   print(a)
end

env = { a = 2, print = print }

-- inherit environment for this call
f()    --> 1
-- set special environment for this call
f(env) --> 2
f()    --> 1
```

Or simply `setfenv(1, getfenv(2))` if you are working only with Lua 5.1 and want to ALWAYS inherit environment.